# Merry Christmas & a Happy New Year

Tags: discussion

With the best wishes from the heart, we wish all Ask Ubuntu members a superb merry Christmas and the best happy new year a geek can find. May you enjoy this special time with the ones you love and receive this soon to be new year with love from everyone.

Thank you all for making Ask Ubuntu what it is today, helping each and everyone when needed and keeping the Ubuntu spirit all of this years, onsite and offsite. You guys rock big time and to me, you guys are the best minds I can find when looking for help.

Keep on using Ubuntu, keep on rocking and big hugs to all of you.

Comment: The year sure went by fast...

Comment: I think your hat is too heavy :)

Comment: it's a mask :) an ugly one.
happy new year luis :)

Comment: And that is a very round number. 74000! :)

Comment: *Votes to Close as off-topic* :P

Comment: Same to you and all other users: all the best wishes for the new year.  And Luis: when do you admit defeat? :-D

Comment: @Rinzwind Tomorrow (sad face)..To all Ask Ubuntu members, vote like crazy for me...only mising 200K points to pass rinzwind lol. Big hugs to all.

Comment: Is that your new years resolution Luis? Pass @Rinzwind? :P Happy New year!

Comment: Hi Luis, I was just thinking that it would be nice to have an overview of other (non-Christian and non-Western) feasts as well. I am think Hanukah, Chinese new year, end of the ramadan. We have many non-Western users... What do you think?

Comment: @don.joey I fully agree. Please edit this "question" and add as many as you feel or add the suggestions in the commands and we will add them here for you. Excellent idea.

Comment: @LuisAlvarado Hmm. Not sure this is practically possible, cf. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_multinational_festivals_and_holidays

Comment: @don.joey To that link, the only appropriate answer would be: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Uh7tgX_Uaqs

Answer (score 21):

Same to you. Also let me jump on the occassion to thank the **mods** for the work they do in keeping this a clean, nice, and friendly environment.

Answer (score 2):

Thank you and wish you the same :)

Answer (score 2):

Thanks, i cant tell in words how much askuntu helps us in daily life for small and very important issues... A very Happy New year to all... Keep it Up #Luis.

Answer (score 2):

I am new to ask ubuntu, so Thanks n Happy Holidays everyone.

Answer (score 1):

Happy Hanukkah and happy new year to you and your family.

Answer (score 1):

Happy Festivus… keeping it alive!